# Linking two seperate sets of data codes without a common identifier

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have two large sets of data. Both sets are a form of structured coding system,and is used to categorize groups of people based on their occupation. The two sets of data have no common identifier. Besides a column that contains a unique identifier each table has a description for said identifier, but although they may be describing similar things the descriptions are not identical.

How do I create a table, that connects the two sets of data, without having to go back and manually try to figure out how to make the connection between the two identifiers. I am not sure if this can be done on Access or SQL. If there is a way to do this, I would like to know what software is maybe out there.

Here's some example data:

```
Table 1:    
Z Identifier    DescriptionA
162000          Pharmacist
3123566         Electronic Repairman
143246          Banker
8444455         Doctor


Table 2:    
Q Identifier    DescriptionB
XX134556        COPY/PRINT/SCAN EQUIP
666Q1224        DRUGS
722WWYZ         Financial Svc 
8456435T        Medical Services
15666PP         Health Services
```

Desired Output:

```
Table 3:                     
Z Identifier    DescriptionA      Q Identifier  DescriptionB    
162000          Pharmacist        666Q1224      DRUGS                           
3123566         Electr Repairman  XX134556      COPY/PRINT/SCAN EQUIP           
143246          Banker            722WWYZ       Financial Svc           
8444455         Doctor            8456435T      Medical Services
```

Comment: Please give a small sample of the two sets of data and what you want the outcome to be to in order solidify this currently abstract problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
Table 1:    
Z Identifier    DescriptionA
162000          Pharmacist
3123566         Electronic Repairman
143246          Banker
8444455         Doctor


Table 2:    
Q Identifier    DescriptionB
XX134556        COPY/PRINT/SCAN EQUIP
666Q1224        DRUGS
722WWYZ         Financial Svc 
8456435T        Medical Services
15666PP         Health Services


Output:                     
Z Identifier    DescriptionA      Q Identifier  DescriptionB    
162000          Pharmacist        666Q1224      DRUGS                           
3123566         Electr Repairman  XX134556      COPY/PRINT/SCAN EQUIP           
143246          Banker            722WWYZ       Financial Svc           
8444455         Doctor            8456435T      Medical Services
```

Comment: I think I might have to literally go back and manually try to make connection, but literally have 100s of thousands of codes.

Comment: It seems you would somehow have to connect the descriptions. I'll try to find a clever way to do this, possibly through some lexical type of library like [this one](http://www.nltk.org/) .

Answer (score 0):

Conventional tools that you are used to (like Access, Excel, and SQL) can only go so far with comparing the meaning and usage of words.

In other words (forgive the pun), in order to do this, you need some sort of [natural language processing toolkit (NLPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_natural_language_processing#Natural_language_processing_toolkits). Along with that, you also need some knowledge of how to program, because I don't think there exists front-end interfaces that can give you the output you want given only the input you listed by just filling out some forms.

So with that in mind, in order to solve your problem (I'll assume you know how to program and can pick up a NLPT in a language of your choice), you need to do the following:

1. Put your two datasets in some tables.
2. Manipulate DescriptionA and DescriptionB to be something meaningful to the NLPT you are using. They won't like a string such as "COPY/PRINT/SCAN/ EQUIP". They'll want the slashes removed and the words separated.
3. Compare DescriptionA with DescriptionB in a permutation-style manner by using a `path_similarity` type of function in the library. For example `path_similarity('animal.definition1', 'dog.definition1')` should return a high value, say .60, while `path_similarity('animal.definition1', 'book.definition1')` should return a low value, like .10.
4. If the `path_similarity` is above a certain value (up for you to decide), join the two items together and append them as a single row to a results table, while removing them from their respective tables. Continue doing this until the list is exhausted of DescriptionA greater than a certain similarity to a DescriptionB. Then do something else with the rows that are left in Table 1 and Table 2.

This should all be fairly easy to do programmatically. You may find you are not getting proper matches in some places with this method because you are randomly choosing two words to compare. Because of that, you may want to find another algorithm other than just permutations, perhaps one that looks at the statistics of the `path_similarity` of every piece of your data to every other piece and acts more appropriately.

Additionally, you may want to allow more than two words to be paired up. For example; "lumberjack", "tree cutter", and "tree chopper" make more sense to be grouped in one row with an additional two columns created than to throw one of them out who will likely be left without a pair. All of the problems I just listed in this paragraph, ***I'm sure*** are not new problems and you can search around the internet in order to solve them. Best of luck!